# Consultar Varios Campos y a la vez mostrarlos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Necesito ayuda con algo, tengo una base de datos con la tabla `basede` y otra f`rasesh`, en basede hay unos campos `Frases H1`, `Frases H2`, `Frases H3`, los cuales contienen un código que esta guardado en frasesh, cada código trae una frase, entonces necesito que me compare los campos Frases H1, Frases H2, Frases H3, todos a la vez y me traiga a pantalla las frases deacuerdo a ese código, el código ya lo tengo casi listo, pero sólo me da para mostrar el de Frases H1, nose como podría concatenar los otros dos campos.

Este es el código que llevo hasta el momento, con el cual estoy intentando hacer esto

```
    <?php
                        //$sql =  mysqli_query( "SELECT Frase H1 FROM 'basede' WHERE id='".$idproduc."'");
                        //$sqli = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT Frase FROM 'frasesh' WHERE id='".$sql."'");
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `basede` WHERE id='".$idproduc."'";
                        $sqlquery = $conexion->query($sql);

                        $Muestra = $sqlquery->fetch_array();


                        $sqli = "SELECT Frase FROM `frasesh` WHERE id='".$Muestra['Frase H1']."' ";

                        $sql_query = $conexion->query($sqli);

                        $Muestra1 = $sql_query->fetch_array();



                ?>  
                <th class="catorce"><h3><?php echo $Muestra1['Frase'];?></h3></th>
                <?php







                ?>
```

Comment: podrias mostrar como tienes definidas las tablas ?..

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, sobre todo por ciertos términos que usas. ¿A qué te refieres con esto: *entonces necesito que me compare los campos Frases H1, Frases H2, Frases H3, todos a la vez y me traiga a pantalla las frases deacuerdo a ese código*, lo que no entiendo es el ´término *compare*, parecería más bien que lo que necesitas es que filtre por esos datos, no que compare ¿? Ayudaría que pongas la estructura de las tablas y un breve ejemplo del resultado que esperas.